# Fixmbr on attached notebook hard drive - possible?

Tags: hard-drive, mbr, bsod

I have a blue screen on my notebook during boot and can't get to the recovery console.

I've removed the hard drive from the notebook and inserted it into another PC. Can I use `fixmbr` on the hard drive?

Comment: Of course, if your system is getting far enough through the bootstrap process that it is able to present a blue screen of death at all, the bootstrap program in your MBR almost certainly isn't going to be the problem … .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to run fixmbr from recovery console via the other system.

Answer (score 0):

[This documentation for fixmbr](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/bootcons_fixmbr.mspx?mfr=true) That might be of use to you. 
The syntax you're after is `fixmbr [device_name]`

The name can be obtained by using the `map` command in the recovery console. Documentation for Map is [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/bootcons_fixmbr.mspx?mfr=true)